# Cannot upload image path to database in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload user pic to database using the `Storage` facade. I used this `php artisan storage:link` to create a symbolic link and all, but the file path is neither uploaded to database, nor am I getting any kind of error

Here are my codes

**Controller**

```
public function edituser_pic(Request $request){
  if(Auth::check()){
          $u_id = $request->id; 
          
         if($request->hasFile('mypic')){
              $path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('profile_image',$request->mypic);

              $profilepic = $path;
         }else{
            $profilepic='';
         }
         DB::table('users')->where('id',$u_id)->update(['profilepic'=>$profilepic]);

         return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'path'=>$profilepic,
         ]);
   }
}
```

In **Blade** (while trying to access the image)

```
<img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="{{url('storage/'.Auth::user()->profilepic)}}" alt="AB" />
```

**Upload form code**

```
<h2>Edit Profile Picture</h2>
        <form id='profilepic' autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf" value="{{Session::token()}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id='id' value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
          <label>Select an image to upload : <br><br>(only jpg, jpeg,png files are allowed)</label><br><br>
          <input type="file" name="mypic" id="mypic" class="text-white">
          <div class="error text-danger"></div>
          <button type="submit" class="buttons bttn" id='editprofilepic'>Upload Image</button>
          <button type="button" class="cancelb">Cancel</button>
        </form>
<script>
//see below
</script>
```

**Script**

```
 $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param * 1000000)
}, 'File size must be less than {0} MB');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("extension", function(value, element, param) {
  param = typeof param === "string" ? param.replace(/,/g, '|') : "png|jpe?g|gif";
  return this.optional(element) || value.match(new RegExp(".(" + param + ")$", "i"))
}, "Please enter a value with a valid extension.");
   var v = $('#profilepic').validate({
       rules:{
        mypic:{
          required:true,
          extension: "jpg|jpeg|png",
          filesize:true,
        },
      },
      messages:{
        mypic:{
           required:"Please select an image file. If you dont't want a profile pic, please use the cancel button",
           extension:"Image files with the following extensions are allowed - .jpg, .jpeg, .png",
           filesize: "Maximum size of the image - 5 MB",
        },
      },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.each(function () {
                $(this).next("div .error").html(error);
            });
        },
    }); 
    
    $('#editprofilepic').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('#profilepic').valid()){
         $.ajax({
              url: 'edituser_pic',
              method:'post',
              cache: false,
              processData:true,   //Required
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              data:{
                   '_token' :$('#csrf').val(),
                   'id'     : $('#id').val(),
                   'mypic'  : $('#mypic').val(),
              },
              success:function e(response){
                console.log(response.path);
                 if(response.success== true){
                  Command: toastr["success"]("You will now be redirected..","Profile Picture updated.")
                            toastr.options = {
                              "closeButton": false,
                              "debug": false,
                              "newestOnTop": false,
                              "progressBar": true,
                              "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
                              "preventDuplicates": false,
                              "onclick": null,
                              "showDuration": "300",
                              "hideDuration": "1000",
                              "timeOut": "5000",
                              "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                              "showEasing": "swing",
                              "hideEasing": "linear",
                              "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                              "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
                              
                            }
                           setTimeout(function(){ location.replace('http://localhost/LaraTest/public/profile');},5500); 
                  }else{
                     Command: toastr["warning"]("Some error","Please try later")
                            toastr.options = {
                              "closeButton": false,
                              "debug": false,
                              "newestOnTop": false,
                              "progressBar": true,
                              "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
                              "preventDuplicates": false,
                              "onclick": null,
                              "showDuration": "300",
                              "hideDuration": "1000",
                              "timeOut": "5000",
                              "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                              "showEasing": "swing",
                              "hideEasing": "linear",
                              "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                              "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
                              
                            }
                            noofsubmits = 0;

                  }
              },
              error:function es(response){
                swal({
                  title:"Some error",
                  text:"Please try later",
                  icon:"warning",
                  button:true
                });
               
              }

          }); //ajax ends
        
      }
    });
```

Comment: what is stored in database location put in question for better understand

Comment: @KamleshPaul Nothing is stored. That's the problem in the first place

Comment: Is the file being uploaded? Missing a `method="post"` in your form? What's the `action` of your form, where do you post that form to?

Comment: @brombeer I used `ajax` submit. I edited my code to include the script

Comment: You just asked the same question a few minutes ago. Please do not post twice the same question

Comment: @ml59 I left out a lot of info , so I deleted that post and asked a new one with updated info

Comment: have you run php artisan storage:link ?

Comment: @Syazany Yes. I did. The problem is the Controller part cannot specify a path name. I tried `console.log($profilepic)`-it was blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment to **@Syazany**, it seems like the the file is not being sent properly via ajax request to the controller. You can do either of the two things.

**Option 1** ->

Post the form using the `Submit` button and **NOT** using Ajax. This should send the file name, temporary path to the Controller. If using this method, don't forget to use `method="post"` and `action="somewhere.php"` in the `form` tag.

**Option 2** ->

Use `FormData` as below to send the form data using ajax -

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("profilepic"));

$.ajax({
        url: 'edituser_pic',
        method:'post',
        cache: false,
        processData:false,   //Required
        contentType: false,  //Required
        data:formData,
        success: function(){
         //do something for success            
         },
        error: function(){
         //do something for error
          },

});
```

**P.S-**

```
processData:false,   //Required
contentType: false,  //Required
```

are necessary if using `FormData`

Comment: That does it. Thanks a lot for saving my day

Comment: However, I don't want to use `submit`. I will go with `ajax`.